# How to recover deleted shortcuts in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, shortcut

As in any other text editor, it is also possible to use the shortcuts Ctrl+Z (undo) or Ctrl+Y (restore) in Eclipse.
After a restart these shortcuts are no longer available and I can't find a way to create my own shortcuts to restore these functions.

I already checked the shortcuts under 'Window' -> 'Preferences' -> 'General' -> 'Keys'. There the two desired functions do not appear any more (see picture). 
In addition I tried unsuccessfully to use another workspace.

[image]

Comment: What eclipse version do you use? plattform? os?

Comment: what about the keys if your create a new/clean workspace? (This workspace/installation look corrupt for me, can you click on "Restore command" ? if it fails, then you have broke your eclipse)

Comment: You know that you can File... -> Export -> Preferences  -> Keys....to a file (form a working version) and then do Import on this workspace.

Comment: Do you have additional plug-ins installed into your Eclipse? If yes, which ones?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I use Eclipse Oxygen on Windows 7. The button "Restore command" was not helpful, but I'll try the Export/Import and I'll give an update, whether it worked.

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen (4.7) is pretty old. The current version is Eclipse 2019-06 (4.12). If [upgrading](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades) does not fix your issue, please tell which additional plug-ins do you have installed (also commands without key bindings should be shown, so I guess export/import will not help).